# How do I create securely password protected .xls files in Excel 2010 from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, encryption, ms-office, office-2010

I found that in Excel 2010 (and 2007), when you try and choose one of the more secure types of encryption, it seems to silently ignore your settings, leaving you with a file that can be cracked in seconds at [decryptum](http://www.decryptum.com) for example.

This does not apply to the new file formats that are AES encrypted by default, only when you are saving down to the 97-2003 format.

This is the macro I create in the workbook:

```
Sub enc()
  Me.SetPasswordEncryptionOptions _
    PasswordEncryptionProvider:= "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider", _
    PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm:= "RC4", _
    PasswordEncryptionKeyLength:=128, _
    PasswordEncryptionFileProperties:=True
  Me.SaveAs _
    Filename:="encryption_test.xls", _
    FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="password"
End Sub
```

It is quite easy to get Excel 2003 to (correctly) output with these encryption settings by omitting the FileFormat parameter:

```
Sub enc()
  Me.SetPasswordEncryptionOptions _
    PasswordEncryptionProvider:= "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider", _
    PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm:= "RC4", _
    PasswordEncryptionKeyLength:=128, _
    PasswordEncryptionFileProperties:=True
  Me.SaveAs _
    Filename:="encryption_test.xls", _
    Password:="password"
End Sub
```

decryptum then fails to decrypt as I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? If it is a bug, how do I work around it?

I've added a solution of sorts for Excel 2010 below, but I'm hoping for something simpler, and preferably something that works for 2007 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for Office 2010:

1. add the office 2010 administrative template (office14.adm)
2. edit "User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Office 2010\Security Settings\Encryption type for password protected Office 97-2003 files" to "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider,RC4,128" (without the quotes)

Answer (score 6):

It's because RC4 isn't enabled with Office 2007/2010 - you'll have to manually do exactly what you are doing with the admin template.

To prove this point, in Excel 2010, do your routine above and then open your "encryption_test.xls" file and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to go to the VBE. Then run the following (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate window first):

```
Sub CheckEncryption()
    Dim aw As Workbook: Set aw = ActiveWorkbook
    With aw
        Debug.Print .PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm
        Debug.Print .PasswordEncryptionFileProperties
        Debug.Print .PasswordEncryptionKeyLength
        Debug.Print .PasswordEncryptionProvider
    End With
End Sub
```

What you'll probably see are the values of 1) *Office Standard*, 2) *False*, 3) *40*, and 4) *Office*. What this means is that as RC4 isn't being used; encryption defaults to standard - and crummy/old - Excel encryption. Obviously RC4 is thought of as pretty crummy too by MSFT, so use of it has been a bit hobbled in the newer Office clients.

See these two articles:

- [Plan cryptography and encryption
  settings for Office 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179125.aspx)
- [Plan document protection settings in
  the 2007 Office system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179125%28office.12%29.aspx)

**Footnote**: The `FileFormat` portion of the `SaveAs` routine isn't culprit here. It's only doing what the CryptoAPI is telling it to do. In fact, from Excel 2010 VBA, you could use Excel 2003's `SaveAs`, which is slightly different and it wouldn't make a difference (from Excel 2010, it's a hidden routine that can be accessed like `ActiveWorkbook.[_SaveAs]  Filename:="encryption_test.xls", Password:="password"`.)

Comment: "you'll have to manually do exactly what you are doing with the admin template" - how do I do that? Is there a way of doing it 'manually' from VBA?

Comment: @JackPDouglas: There is no way to set this manually from VBA. It's a Group Policy setting, as you mentioned in your workaround answer above. That is the actual way to do it in Office 2010, not a workaround. You can apply this policy to either the local machine or to all machines via a domain controller. See:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400327.aspx.

Comment: +1 because your comments are informative - but I am still hoping for an answer that is simpler to implement than mine. For example, a solution just involving HKLM registry settings would be much easier to implement than installing this admin template on every PC in our office (and I'm not sure I can do it on the DC because it is a Windows 2000 domain)

Comment: PS, don't you agree that this is an glaringly bad decision on MS part? VBA code that produced [pretty secure](http://www.oraxcel.com/projects/encoffice/help/How_safe_is_Excel_encryption.html) encrypted files in Office 2003 suddenly produces easily crackable files in 2007/2010, _without warning you_?

Comment: @JackPDouglas: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news on this one. I totally agree with your statement that security from 2007/2010 to 2003 has kind of taken a complete step backwards given that it defaults to really poor security without any warning. But unfortunately you're not going to find any other kind of workaround like a registry setting on this one - it is what it is. For a DC GPO deployment you'll need Windows Server 2003 or later.

Comment: @JackPDouglas: You just need the Office 2007 admin template, which is part of http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=92D8519A-E143-4AEE-8F7A-E4BBAEBA13E7&displaylang=en. Install the office12.adm template and then under Security Settings | Encryption type for password protected Office 97-2003 files, set as you have with Office 2010 template.

Comment: that didn't work for me - it silently fails and the fials can be cracked on decryptum. I'll try again on a freshly installed VM

Comment: I can't comment on what decryptum uses to crack Excel files - I have no idea what they can/can't do. I'm just talking about general Excel 2003 security for RC4 from Office 2007/2010.

Comment: decryptum does not even try to decrypt if "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" is used. I just use it to test whether Office has really used the settings or not...

Comment: I just tested it from Office 2007. First I installed the Office 12 admin template, enabled the *Encryption type for password protected Office 97-2003 files* and set as *Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider,RC4,12*. Then I opened a workbook, saved it as test.xls, opened the VBE and put in your code above (except your `Me.` was replaced with `Dim aw As Workbook: Set aw = ActiveWorkbook` and `aw.` was used in place of `Me.`). Then I ran the code, confirmed settings with my `CheckEncryption` routine. Then I did the trial of decryptum and it could not decrypt...see next comment

Comment: The error received from decryptum was **Error: [Sorry, the file you uploaded is encrypted by Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider and is not supported.]** Note that the routine of yours I used from Excel 2007 was the second one (the one without `FileFormat:=xlExcel8`)

Comment: Thinking about why this may have failed for you Jack, I think it is because your workbook is still in xslx format when you set the encryption. First, get it in xsl format with a SaveAs, then set the encryption, then set the password, then save it again. That should work well.